# php mysql last visit

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have website where the user can show his last visit to the website every time he logs in.
the type of last_activity column in the database is 'time'.

I made a code that shows the current date and save it in a variable $currentDate

and then set variable $currentDate into last_activity column in the database and update the column every time the user logs in.

but when I test the code I get this result:

your last visit: 00:00:00

the type of last_activity column in the database is 'time'.

here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include('db.php');

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Riyadh');   
$currentDate = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());


if(isset($_SESSION['Email']) === true)
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `lastactivity` = ".$currentDate." WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."'");   

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."'";
    $run = mysql_query($query);  

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
    {
        $name = $row[1]; 
        $active = $row[10];

        echo 'welcome '.$name;
        echo 'your last visit '.$active;
        ;
```

Comment: SET `lastactivity` vs SET `last_activity` ??

Comment: I made this but it didn't work. when I echo $currentDate I get the correct current date but when I add it to the database it gives me this date 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the type `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` to store a datetime value instead of `TIME`. The `TIME` datatype has no notion of dates:

> [The TIME Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html)
>
> MySQL retrieves and displays TIME values in 'HH:MM:SS' format (or
>   'HHH:MM:SS' format for large hours values). TIME values may range from
>   '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59'.
>
> ...
>
> **Invalid TIME values are converted to '00:00:00'.**

Because of that you get

```
your last visit: 00:00:00
```

back from the database as your output.

> The [DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)
>
> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

**Edit:**

`TIMESTAMP` and in newer MySQL versions `DATETIME` columns have nice features, i.e. automatic update:

> [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)
>
> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically
>   initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the
>   current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and
>   for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table.

**Edit 2:**

Furthermore produces

```
$currentDate = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
```

no valid format of an `DATETIME` literal. You could use STR_TO_DATE() to convert your value to DATETIME, but I wouldn't recommend this. Better you change your UPDATE statement using the MySQL function NOW() to:

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `lastactivity` = NOW() WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."'");
```

You can format your DATETIME value, while retrieving it from MySQL with [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and give this computed column a name:

```
$query = "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(lastactivity, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i%s %p') as last_activity FROM `table` WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['Email']."'";
$run = mysql_query($query);  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{
    $name = $row[1]; 
    $active = $row["last_activity"];   // access to the column by column name
    // ...
```

**Note**
I recommend to switch from the deprecated mysql_* functions to PDO or mysqli with prepared statements and placeholders instead of concatenation of an sql statement.

Comment: I tried to change the type to DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP Types

but it gives me the same ressult: